# Eurail Global Pass - Is it valid for travel within city local transport?

Tags: trains, budget, eurail

We are a family of 4 persons (children 9 years and 7 years) and are travelling to Berlin. We would be there for 40 days. We plan to travel to nearby cities within Germany and other countries over weekends. 
After that we plan to travel for next 15 days to Italy, Switzerland, France  etc.

How good an option is Eurail Global Pass (2 months consecutive validity pass) is for this travel? Is this pass valid for internal/ local travel in any city that we may visit during this trip?

Comment: Do you mean Eurail?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/37803/22140

Answer (score 5):

### Eurail Pass Explained

In general the Eurail pass is valid on train lines only. Metropolitan public transport is usually not included in such rail-passes. [The Man in Seat 61 says](http://www.seat61.com/Railpass-and-Eurail-pass-guide.htm#quick%20guide%20to%20railpasses):

> **Railpasses cover all the trains run by the main national train operator** in each country covered by the pass, including local trains, suburban trains, regional trains, inter-city trains & international trains.  [...]
>
> **Railpasses don't cover city metro/underground/subway trains, trams or buses** as these are usually run by urban transport authorities, not by the national rail operator.

Having said this, note that [Eurail has a page listing benefits per country.](http://www.eurail.com/eurail-passes/pass-benefits) From there you can gather all the information required for your trip. All in all, it's up to you to figure out if this is a viable option, depending on your itinerary and budget.

### Benefits in Germany

To give you a few examples, [the benefits for Germany include travelling on S-Bahn trains](http://www.eurail.com/eurail-passes/pass-benefits/benefits-germany):

> #### Hop on the S-Bahn and discover major German cities
>
> A Eurail pass is also valid on the S-Bahn (suburban metro railways) networks that DB operates in major German cities. The S-Bahn can be recognized by its logo (a white S on a green background)

#### S-Bahn Validity in Berlin

[Others have mentioned that the pass isn't valid on Berlin's S-Bahn.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46372/eurail-global-pass-is-it-valid-for-travel-within-city-local-transport#comment88041_46376) I coulndn't find any mention of this, but I welcome edits. [The Eurail webpage for Germany however says that the pass is indeed valid on the S-Bahn, and it mentions a station in Berlin](http://www.eurail.com/europe-by-train/germany):

> Your Eurail pass is also valid on the S-bahn rapid transit system. Take the S-Bahn to Bahnhof Potsdamer Platz for the panoramic observation deck.

Moreover, [this post on a related thread from Rick Steves' dating December 2014 says that the Eurail pass should be valid for the Berlin S-Bahn routes](https://community.ricksteves.com/travel-forum/germany/eurail-pass-global-privileges-in-germany-u-bahn-s-bahn#711155):

> The Eurail pass includes all S-Bahn that are run by German Rail. That might now include all; at one time there was a line in Berlin that was not included.

### Benefits in Austria

The same benefit seems to apply to Austria. Indeed [the Eurail pass allows to travel for free on the S-Bahn in Vienna and Innsbruck](http://www.eurail.com/eurail-passes/pass-benefits/benefits-austria):

> #### Get free transportation on the S-Bahn
>
> Eurail pass holder can travel for free on the S-Bahn in Vienna and Innsbruck.

### Benefits in France and Italy

The benefit pages for France and Italy however mention nothing of the like.

Comment: [Note that here on TSE we don't do travel itineraries. They are indeed off-topic.](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: There is a [website for all your travel questions](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37803/when-using-rail-passes-in-germany-can-i-use-it-in-urban-trains-as-well-u-ba/37812#37812) where you can find more than a mention of this ;-)

Comment: @Relaxed Thanks. :) [The Eurail page for Germany mentions using the pass on Berlin's S-Bahn stations.](http://www.eurail.com/europe-by-train/germany). Am I interpreting this wrong, or can this be a new feature? [This post on Rick Steves' kinda suggests the latter.](https://community.ricksteves.com/travel-forum/germany/eurail-pass-global-privileges-in-germany-u-bahn-s-bahn#711155)

Comment: S-Bahn in Vienna at least brings very limited advantages. They are not dedicated tracks and normal trains serve pretty much the same stops and you're going to need the public transport system (Wiener Linien) to get to the main tourist destinations anyways. Looking at a map of Berlin, it seems much the same story.

Comment: You are right, this rule changed, [this table](http://www.diebefoerderer.de/uploads/media/Internationale_Passangebote_-_SCIC.pdf) unambiguously confirms this.

Comment: I just found an earlier version that already mentioned S-Bahn Berlin, contrary to what the Rail Europe staffer answered on the forum, so I am not so sure anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to advise for or against Railpasses, such as Eurail or Interrail. [The Man in Seat 61 lists some arguments](http://www.seat61.com/Railpass-and-Eurail-pass-guide.htm).

Without knowing where you want to go, how flexible you want to be and how old you are, it is difficult to advise for or against.

There is also a thread on this site: [What is preferable, Eurail Pass or Buying Pass on the spot?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6358/what-is-preferable-eurail-pass-or-buying-pass-on-the-spot)

In principle, the Eurail pass is not valid on local transport networks. There are however exceptions. For example, in Germany, the pass is valid on the so-called S-Bahn. These are networks of suburban trains that you can find in any major city.

Comment: Valid on the S-Bahn… except in Berlin

Comment: thanks. i am 40 years my wife is 42. We wish to use berlin as our base for first 40 days and go to Krakow, prague in the east, Hamburg, Kiel in the North and Amsterdam, Brussels Cologne in the West over consecutive weekends from there. Later we want to go from Berlin toVienna, Venice, Rome, Milan, Switzerland, Paris, Nice, Paris and back to Berlin over the last 15 days.

Comment: our kids are 9 and 7.

Comment: Are these passes valid for local trains/ metro/ tubes and trams and buses in the cities( mainly Berlin, Bamburg, Amsterdam, Prague,Vienna, Rome, Milan etc.) of  all the participating countries.

Comment: Is it an economical proposition for the kind of trip indicated above?

Comment: @AmitMittal Have you read PESEUR's answer? It seems it already addresses your questions. But we can't make the decisions for you…

Comment: @AmitMittal The way forward would be to simulate an itinerary and check what it would cost when buying point to point tickets ...

Comment: If you want to be pragmatic, you should also consider flights and long distance busses for some of the legs. And as you travel a lot within Germany, a "BahnCard" might be profitable.